# Find a range of text with specific formatting with Word interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a MS Word add-in that needs to extract text from a range of text based solely on its formatting: in my case in particular, if the text is underlined or struck through, the range of characters/words that are underlined or struck through need to be found so that I can keep track of them.

My first idea was to use `Range.Find`, as is [outlined here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7d13z59.aspx), but that won't work when I have no idea what the string is that I'm looking for:

```
var rng = doc.Range(someStartRange, someEndRange);

rng.Find.Forward = true;
rng.Find.Format = true;
// I removed this line in favor of putting it inside Execute()
//rng.Find.Text = "";

rng.Find.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;

// this works
rng.Find.Execute("");

int foundNumber = 0;

while (rng.Find.Found)
{
    foundNumber++;
    // this needed to be added as well, as per the link above
    rng.Find.Execute("");
}

MessageBox.Show("Underlined strings found: " + foundNumber.ToString());
```

I would happily parse the text myself, but am not sure how to do this while still knowing the formatting. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

**EDIT:**

I changed my code to fix the find underline issue, and with that change the while loop never terminates. More specifically, `rng.Find.Found` finds the underlined text, but it finds the same text over and over, and never terminates.

**EDIT 2:**
Once I added the additional `Execute()` call inside the while loop, the find functioned as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
rng.Find.Font.Underline  = wdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;
```

(At the moment you are setting the formatting for the specified rng, rather than the formatting for the Find)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't fix the underlying issue: right now, the while loop goes on forever.

Comment: After I made your change and the one in my second edit, the Find worked as desired. Marking your answer as correct. Thanks!