# I want to remove the underline. But the code below is too slow

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I want to remove the underline(wdUnderlineWavy).
But the code below is too slow. The more characters the slower they become.
Is there any faster way?

```
    void remove_underline()
    {

        Word.Range range;
        for (int i = 1; i < Application.ActiveDocument.Characters.Count; i++)
        {
            range = Application.ActiveDocument.Characters[i];


            if (range.Font.Underline == Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineWavy
                   && (range.Font.UnderlineColor == (Word.WdColor)254 ||
                   range.Font.UnderlineColor == (Word.WdColor)32769 ||
                   range.Font.UnderlineColor == (Word.WdColor)16711681))
            {
                range.Font.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineNone;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How long does it take to run? How long do you need it to take?

Comment: Could you use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072679/find-a-range-of-text-with-specific-formatting-with-word-interop to narrow down the text you need to iterate through (i.e. just focus on underlined text rather than **every character**)?

Comment: You could find a character, and keep testing to see if the next is also underlined until you have the section, and THEN remove the underline of the group..  which would make your document likely smaller and your work faster.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < Applicat ... ` Is it really 1-based?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about how much of the document needs to have this removed? The entire document? A certain part?

Comment: @Fildor Some are in Office, from memory.

Comment: @mjwills I know, I just wanted to make sure it's not overlooked. It may well be.

Comment: If it is 1-based, `<` should be `<=`. So there is an off by one error at one of the ends. :)

Comment: It's a certain part(The underlined word) @Cindy Meister

Comment: if i==Application.ActiveDocument.Characters.Count, Application.ActiveDocument.Characters[i] <- '\n'. So I set '<'. @mjwills

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll give it a try. @BugFinder

Comment: I meant any particular part of the document, or throughout the document...

Comment: Check the entire part of the document. @CindyMeister

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    void remove_underline()
    {
            Word.Range range;
            range = Application.ActiveDocument.Content;
            remove_underline(range, 254);
            remove_underline(range, 32769);
            remove_underline(range, 16711681);
    }
    void remove_underline(Word.Range range, int colorIndex) {
        range.Find.ClearFormatting();
        range.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
        range.Find.Text = "";
        range.Find.Font.UnderlineColor = (Word.WdColor)colorIndex;
        range.Find.Font.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineWavy;
        range.Find.Replacement.Text = "";
        range.Find.Replacement.Font.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineNone;
        range.Find.Execute(Format: true,Replace:Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);

    }
```

I solved the problem.
refer : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/974a3a27-3ce9-43c6-9bbc-fbc39c6c0592/i-want-to-remove-the-underline-but-the-code-below-is-too-slow?forum=vsto

Comment: Exactly what I was about to post... Glad you found it.